# How to place a video at a specific location on top a larger static background image using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, video-processing

I have installed a current build of `ffmpeg` in order to gain access to the `-filter_complex` option in hopes to be able to use a video as an overlay over a static background image that's larger than the video.

Initially I'm simply trying to get the overlay of the video over the static background image to work with the following command (which does not work):

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.png -i overlay.mov -filter_complex overlay -shortest -y output.mov`

The `output.mov` only has a single frame composed of the `background.png` file with no video overlay.

How can I make this work and additionally add a specific coordinate location for the video atop the background?

**BONUS**: with a singular command, is it also possible to resize the overlay video to a larger size while placing it atop the bg image?

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm attempting to build: http://j.mp/NT3cHd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That command works fine for me (using `0.11.1.git-56ae592 built on Jul 19 2012` or `N-42914-gf5a5b43 built on Jul 26 2012`); the problem is elsewhere.  What version of FFmpeg are you using?  (There are current builds for a number of versions.)  Are there any messages in the output suggesting that something's not working?

To answer your other questions:

- You can set the coordinates of the [overlay filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#overlay-1)  to `x=100`, `y=50` (from top-left) like so:

  ```
  ... -filter_complex overlay=100:50 ...
  ```
- Resizing the <strike>background</strike> overlay can be done using the [scale filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#scale):

  ```
  ... -filter_complex "[0] scale=1280:960 [bg]; [bg][1] overlay" ...
  ```

  ```
  ... -filter_complex "[1] scale=1280:960 [over]; [0][over] overlay" ...
  ```
- As an addendum, you shouldn't need `-filter_complex` to do this, something like:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i over.mov -vf "movie=background.png [bg]; [bg][in] overlay" out.mp4
  ```

  should also work.  I say "should" because that command actually segfaults with the versions of FFmpeg I tested on, but the command syntax can handle what you want to do without `-filter_complex`.

Comment: `ffmpeg -version` -> ffmpeg version git-2012-07-31-d2ca5dd
built on Jul 31 2012 16:21:59 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Comment: `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.png -i overlay_video.mov -filter_complex overlay -shortest -y output.mov` yields: http://j.mp/R5HGm4

Comment: @ylluminate Something's wrong with `overlay_video.mov`: duration 0.04 seconds and png format.  Check that it wasn't accidentally overwritten and plays normally with other playback software.

Comment: I can indeed play overlay_video.mov just fine.  Should I attempt to convert it to a "better" format first?

Comment: @ylluminate That's just weird.  Converting it might snap FFmpeg out of thinking that it's an image and not a movie, but something's amiss there.  What does `ffprobe -show_format -show_streams overlay_video.mov` show?

Comment: Alright, this is making more sense.  It turns out after running `ffprobe -show_frames overlay_video.mov` I see that indeed the video is corrupted.  It wasn't overwritten, but rather another developer accidentally ran a command on it earlier today I discovered after looking through the ZSH history.  I've included an example at the top in the comments of the desired output.  I need to resize the overlay video (not the static bg image as it's already the correct size), whereas your example appears to resize the bg.  Could you provide an example the other way around?

Comment: Excellent.  That does it!  I am curious, it seems easy enough to `-loop 1` the static bg image, however what if I want to loop the overlay video x times whilst still using the `-shortest` option to terminate after it's looped x times?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14719/discussion-between-ylluminate-and-blahdiblah)

Comment: I ended up using the `concat` filter as follows to create a loop of 5 times for the overlay vid: `ffmpeg -i video.mov -i video.mov -i video.mov -i video.mov -i video.mov -filter_complex 'concat=n=5' -y overlay_video.mov && ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.png -i overlay_video.mov -filter_complex "[1] scale=660:660 [over]; [0][over] overlay=10:10" -shortest -y output.mov`